# ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters with javascript remoting

Tags: visualforce, controller, javascript-remoting

I am working with a VF page that uses javascript remoting to do some work that an earlier developer made.  There won't be an easy way to move the remoted method into the controller as a normal method that I can access through the page because it is used all over the place on other pages and has some pretty 'waiting to finish' messages built into the javascript as well.

The problem I have is that I need to get the ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters() to be accessible here.  I cannot grab specific values to pass into the method either because the parameters will be dynamic.  Is there any way to do this or is my only option to do all of the work to no longer use remoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dphil Your going to have to pass the current page to the `@RemoteAction`, because these methods are `global` they do not have context with the controller they are a part of, as the `ApexPages` class does.

Comment: I can actually pass the current page into it?  What would that look like?

Comment: Could I just use  {!$currentpage.parameters} and would that convert to a Map in the apex side?

Comment: Dereference the current page in the page's markup via Visualforce and use it as an argument in the JS call. Off hand not sure what the formatting of the `{!$currentPage.parameters}` looks like in VF

Comment: Yeah, looks like: `myJSFunction('{!$currentPage.parameters}')` (obviously a simplified way of calling it...)

Comment: Whenever I try to save, I get the error: "problem": "Field parameters does not exist. Check spelling.",

Comment: @dphil you might have to get more specific in your reference to [$currentPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm)

Comment: I just ended up creating a variable to hold hte parameters in my control.  Going to wait until Monday to test to see if it worked though.

Comment: Hmmmm, javascript turns the Map parameters into a String for the call to the remote method.  It does pass in what i expect... with the excpetion that it's a String now.