# Correct syntax to pass the parameter to a method via JavaScript (JavaScript remoting doesn't have PageReference context)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a @RemoteAction method which return a List of opportunities via a SOQL statement that needs to use the dynamic 'WHERE Account.Id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')'.

This wasn't working though because it transpires, as per the docs, that JavaScript remoting is async and therefore, there is no PageReference context.

The solution apparently, as per [ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters with javascript remoting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78927/apexpages-currentpage-getparameters-with-javascript-remoting), is to pass the parameter(s) explictly to a a method from JavaScript.

My code is below and although I am not getting any errors when I save the respective VF page (it's actually a VF component, but I don't think that matters) or the method, the data is not being displayed as expected on the Visualforce page.

Can someone please advise?

Thanks,

```
  @RemoteAction //Remote Action to expose method to JavaScript Remoting
public static List<Opportunity> getDatatable(Id accountid){
   return [select name, stagename, createddate, amount from Opportunity WHERE Account.Id=: accountid ORDER by Name ASC ];
           } 

 "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings) { 
                  ChartController.getDatatable('{!$currentPage.parameters.id}')(function(result, event){
```

FYI to readers: another good sources to read: [Do RemoteAction methods have access to page parameters?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11215/do-remoteaction-methods-have-access-to-page-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote action can be called with following syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings) { 

        var recordid='{!$currentPage.parameters.id}';
        alert(recordid);
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.ChartController.getDatatable}',
            recordid, 
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {

                    //your success code

                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    //Your exception handling
                } else {

                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. I am returning this error 'No remoted actions found to resolve '$RemoteAction.ChartController.getDatatable'. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: in which controller you have defined your remote action?

Comment: Ah - sorry, I think I know what the problem was...It was a component that was marked as <apex:component>...I have now added <apex:component controller="ChartController">

Comment: that is correct :)

Comment: Fantastic - this is working now. Many thanks, Himanshu.